# BPEL vs integration framework

Tags: architecture, apache-camel, integration, esb, bpel

What is BPEL and how it's different from integration frameworks like Apache Camel or ESB?

In which aspects these technologies overlap, in which they are unique? When would one choose BPEL over integration framework like Apache Camel or an ESB solution?

Answer (score 2):

A solution based on the ESB is much more flexible.
The solution on the basis of BPEL are well-suited only for SOA, for XML based SOAP Web-services.
You have too few tools. Only clients of the web services as connectors and XSLT as transformation tools.

In the case of an ESB-based solution, you have dozens of connectors and transformation tools, including the ability to work with web services and XSLT.

You are also not limited to choosing a language to write a script in as tightly as possible. Not only XML-based BPEL.

**Updated:** With Apache Camel, for example, you can implement a much larger number of EIPs and you can solve a much larger range of tasks than with BPEL

It's like a galaxy compared to the solar system, like Swiss army knife and a penknife :)